# How can we write regular expression for strings with two periods

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking to write a regex which accepts only ".wms" files.

My current regex is `"  /\.(wms)$/i "`

I'm using this is Rails Model validation and I'm getting this error

```
The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $)
```

How can we get a regex  which all the below match and avoid the above rails error

Regex should allow :

- filename.wms
- filename.zip.wms
- (allow anything which ends in .wms)

Regex should not allow:

- filename.geo
- ilename.zip

Which regex should i use to get this validation right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\A` to match the start of the string and `\z` anchor to match the end of the string. Besides, a period should be escaped to match a literal period. Besides, to match any 0+ chars as many as possible, you may use `.*`.

Thus, you may use

```
/\A.*\.wms\z/
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/xYcNXhqrwh). (The demo regex is modified to use other anchors since the input is a multiline string.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below regular expression

```
([A-Za-z.-_]+.wms)
```

If you check above regular expressions in this link https://regex101.com/
Result will be

```
Match 1
Full match  0-12    `filename.wms`
Group 1.    0-12    `filename.wms`
Match 2
Full match  14-30   `filename.zip.wms`
Group 1.    14-30   `filename.zip.wms`
```

Regards

Comment: If you want any addition info you can send me details.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

`/\w+\.wms$/`

Hope this helps